# Detech wall and change wall color using ARkit swift

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I need to build an app like Asian Paint or Dulux, in which it will detect the wall and user will select color for wall and virtual color will be visible on wall.

Mostly I found example for placing image but I want to change wall color.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find a vertical plane, then add your custom plane with the color you want to paint and put it on the scene.